# Как добавить строчку текста в форму входа в админ панель drupal 7?

Tags: drupal

Имеется сайт http://dik18.ru/cabinet
Как добавить строчку произвольного текста после заголовка Клиентам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function THEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
     case 'user_login':
      $form['#prefix'] = "<p>Cтрочка произвольного текста</p>";
      break;
   }
  }
```

Comment: большое спасибо,но можете сказать куда именно вставлять этот текст?в какой модуль/файл?очень жду ответа)

Comment: В template.php темы. THEMENAME заменить на название темы.

Comment: все круто,спасибо)